# Know the Block ID in CUDA from a given 2D offset

Tags: arrays, cuda, 2d, offset

i've trying to calculate the blockIdx.x and blockIdx.y from a given offset in CUDA but i'm totally mind-blocked. The idea is read data from shared memory when possible and from global memory in other case.

In example, if I've a 1D array of 64 elements and I configure a kernel with 16x1 threads (4 blocks in total) each thread can access to a position using:

```
int idx = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x
```

and i can easily get the blockIdx.x of a given index value from the idx as

```
int blockNumber = idx / blockDim.x;
```

but in a 2D scenario with 8x8 elements and a kernel configuration of 4x4 threads (2x2 blocks in total) each thread accesses to a position using:

```
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
int pitch = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
int idx = x + y * pitch;

int sharedMemIndex = threadIdx.x+threadIdx.y+BLOCK_DIM_X;
__shared_block[sharedMemIndex] = fromGlobalMemory[idx];
__syncthreads();

// ... some operations

int unknow_index = __shared_block[sharedMemIndex];

if ( unknow_index within this block? )
    // ... read from shared memory
else
    // ... read from global memory
```

How can i know the Block ID.x and ID.y at a given idx? i.e. index 34 and 35 are in block (0, 1) and index 36 in block (1, 1). So, if a thread in block (0, 1) read a value of index 35, that thread will know that the value is within its block and will read it from shared memory. The index 35 value will be in stored in the position 11 of the shared memory of the block (0. 1).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. Any thread, in any kernel always has blockIdx.{xyz} available. Why would you ever need to try and calculate it?

Comment: Image you need to do some loads from memory. The first one load value_index_1 = array[idx] and the second loads value_index_2 = array[value_index]. So, if value_index_1 is in the block, i can load from shared memory, else i need to load from global memory.

Comment: You still don't need the to compute the block index value for that. You can compare the difference between a given threads id within the block and the block size to the global thread ID and the index in question. That will tell you whether the index lies within the range of shared memory within the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, I really can't think of a good reason why this is ever necessary, but you can compute the result like this, for an arbitrary index value `idx`(assuming column ordered indexing):

```
int pitch = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
int tidy = idx / pitch; // div(idx,pitch)
int tidx = idx - (pitch * tidy); // mod(idx,pitch)
int bidx = idx / blockDim.x;
int bidy = idy / blockDim.y;
```

that should give you the block coordinates of the index in bidx and bidy.

Comment: This is something like i'm looking for :) but it's not working. In an example of a 2D array of 8x8 elements, with a block size of 4x4 and a grid size of 2x2.- index 35 is in block (0, 1) and index 36 in block (1, 1). With those operations both, index 35 and 36 are in block (2,2). 
I excepted to find in bidx = 0 and bidy = 1 for index = 35. I've added more detailts to the question.

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake in the last two lines. The global (x,y) indices should be divided by the block dimensions not the grid dimensions. Edited to fix this.

Comment: This is something like i'm looking for :) but it's not working. Shouldn't be 
bidx = tidx / blockDim.x
bidy = tidy / blockDim.y
 ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to apply math on **Idx** to find out the X and Y blocks or go backwards from Idx to find the block index. For every thread (Idx) you can find out the Y and X blocks simply by calling the **blockIdx.x** and **blockIdx.y**.

at any point in kernel:

```
int x = blockIdx.x // will give you X block Index at that particular thread
int y = blockIdx.y // will give you Y block Index at that particular thread.
```

**Update:**
If you're dead set on the reverse operation, you need to know the value of pitch and block dimensions

```
   int currentRow = idx/pitch;
   int currentCol = idx%pitch;

   int block_idx_x = currentCol/blockDim.x;
   int block_idx_y = currentRow/blockDim.y;
```

Comment: Hello Jawad, thanks for the answer but i'm looking for a way to calculate those values at a given index without use blockIdx.x and blockIdx.y. It's a reverse operation. Regards!

Comment: I do not get your point. You want to find out the blockIdx.x and blockIdx.y from Idx when you used the same (blockIdx.x and blockIdx.y) to calculate the Idx itself. Anyways, If you want to know the backward maths, see the update in my answer

Comment: Yeah, i've noticed the question was a bit vague. I've updated it to show a case where the index was not calculated from the blockIdx.x and blockIdx.y

Comment: also your answer is correct, not using the % operator is, in my case, 1.4x faster. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are performing unnecessary calculations.

```
idx / blockDim.x
-->(blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x)/blockDim.x
-->(blockIdx.x  + threadIdx.x/blockDim.x)
--> blockIdx.x + 0 (threadIdx.x always less than blockDim.x)
```

You can just use blockIdx.x instead of the convoluted calculation. The same is true for 2D grids (blockIdx.x and blockIdx.y).

Comment: Hello Pavan, thanks for the answer, but i can not figure out what to do with it :). Regards!